# How to update multiple partial view using single ajax Post request Asp.Net Core?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am working on table of web page in Asp .Net Core, whose data is updated by ajax post request.

```
 var params = 'searchString=' + searchString +
'&previousSortField=' + prevSortField +
'&currentSortField=' + CurrentSortField +
'&currentSortOrder=' + sortOrder +
'&pageNumber=' + pageNumber +
'&pageSize=' + PageSize;


const url = '/SampleSubmissionDetail/GetNewData?' + params;
fetch(url ,{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  })
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = responseText;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

I have created a pager in partial view and I need to update with data that I posted using above ajax call. How can I update multiple partial view using ajax post request in Asp .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: Can you post your HTML-view and the controller method "GetNewData"? And why do you POST parameter (feels more like a GET you're looking for)?

Comment: What's your multiple partial views code ? What is the logical relationship between the partial views and the main view ? For rendering a Partial View and JSON Data Using AJAX , you could refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/rendering-a-partial-view-and-json-data-using-ajax-in-Asp-Net/